# Make Stack Pointer to a mmap returned pointer. (Linux, 32bit VM)

Tags: c, linux, pointers, assembly, stack

I'm trying to move my stack pointer to a mmap-ed region to simulate a context switch, but somehow the code below always give a segmentation error:

C:

```
struct savectx {
    void *regs[JB_SIZE];
};

struct savectx* initctx=(struct savectx*)malloc(sizeof(savectx));
void *newsp;
if ((newsp=mmap(0,STACK_SIZE,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,
    MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS,0,0))==MAP_FAILED){
    perror("mmap failed");
}
initctx->regs[4]=newsp;
restorectx(initctx,0);
```

x86:

```
 restorectx:
 movl   4(%esp),%ecx        /*Move jump buffer addr to ecx */
 movl   8(%esp),%eax        /*Longjmp return value */
 movl   (JB_SP*4)(%ecx),%esp    /*JB_SP is defined to be 4,*/
```

The program fails on the last line of the assembly.

For malloc I know that I might have to add 0x000f0000 to the pointer, but what about mmap? Or how do we make the stack adjust to the mmapp-ed location.
(man page for mmap: http://linux.die.net/man/3/mmap, compiled with GCC on ubuntu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem was actually that mmap grows at the opposite direction of the stack (which, sadly, I forgot). So to assign the pointer, I just had to assign (mmaped_stack+stack_size) instead of just the pointer.

Answer (score 4):

Linux (or UN*X in general) already *has* functions to perform this sort of context substitution:

- [`setcontext()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/setcontext.html)
- [`makecontext()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/makecontext.html)

If you use those, you can substitute the entire initial register set (including the stackpointer) by setting up a suitable `ucontext_t` / `struct sigcontext` (the `uc_mcontext` member of `ucontext_t`). Calling `setcontext()` then becomes kind-of an extended `longjmp()`.

A usage example can be found in the [Wikipedia article on `setcontext()`.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setcontext)

For the Linux definition of `ucontext_t`, see:

- `ucontext_t`: [Linux sourcecode,](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=blob;f=include/asm-generic/ucontext.h)
- `struct sigcontext`: [Linux sourcecode, x86 architecture definition,](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=blob;f=arch/x86/include/asm/sigcontext.h)
  (this is architecture-dependent - so x86, ARM, PPC, MIPS, ... all have their own, and this is what contains the register set including the stackpointer).

Comment: Hi. Thank you for answering this. This would functioning the same way my savectx struct does. My question is really how to adjust base and stack pointer to an mmaped region, not really the save context part.

Comment: Edison: Due to the fact that e.g. function calling depends on a valid/consistent stack (for return addresses, and more), you can't just _replace_ the stackpointer, because it's impossible to return from a function that does so. Replacing the stackpointer is part of a context switch whatever the name of the function that does it.

Comment: I'm trying to say: Get `makecontext()` / `setcontext()` working for you as _first step_. Once you're there, look at the sourcecode for those as _second step_. Once you've understood that, make your own experiments reimplementing (parts of) that as _third step_. You're more likely to succeed (and do it properly) that way.